# Write GPS coordinates in text file android

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am writing an simple app which can write GPS coordinates in text by using `FileOutputStream`. The text is successfully created and written with location coordinates. However, the location does not update as frequent as I set in the follow method :

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
```

I set the minTime and minDistance as 0 because I wish to grab as many coordinate as possible. Below is the code in onLocationChanged()

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (location != null) {
        long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
        String millisec = "" + time;
        double lat = location.getLatitude();
        double longe = location.getLongitude();
        loc = millisec + "\t" + lat + "\t" + longe + "\n"; 
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            fos.write(loc.getBytes());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The result does not satisfy my need because I want at least one update per second. Is my method wrong or is there any better way to do this?

Please help.

Comment: Did you got any location(Lat,Long) into your file?

Comment: Have you try with a valure smaller but not 0 as minTime and minDistance? I've not found on Adnroid docs any reference to a feature that maximize the location interval if you use 0 as parameters...

Comment: @MD ya I got the file that I wanted. The result is as what I expected.

Comment: @phemt.latd I tried before, still same =(

Comment: @ChengLawrence try this using GPS_PROVIDER and let me know.

Comment: @MD Wow I thought GPS_PROVIDER should update slower than NETWORK_PROVIDER but seem like I am terribly wrong! It updates very fast o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found on Docs,

> The elapsed time between location updates will never be less than minTime, although it can be more depending on the Location Provider implementation and the update interval requested by other applications.

Location Updates is also dependent on it's own implementation and interval by other apps which have requested updates. So, your minimum time interval is **not** guaranteed by LocationProvider.

Reference : [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)